# aura:handler init event

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

With the following markup we create an action handler that is "fired" when the component is first loaded.

```
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
```

Can someone tell me which part of the above markup actually tells this behaviour to happen ?

Is it the `name="init"` attribute or this `value="{!this}"` ?

I assume `action` just indicates the method to be called invoked from the client side controller and this can be anything like

c.xyz

or

c.abc

Comment: as far as I know; it's both! The handler 'activates' when the _value_ specified (ie 'this') is _initialised_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every aura:handler has attributes it needs to work: name and value (for component events), or event (for application events), and action. Name is a predefined name for system events like init or change. This tells aura:handler which event to attach to. Event specifies an event to attach, which might actually be a custom event. Value specifies what the event is attached to: for an init, it will be the current component ("`{!this}`"); for other types of events, you might bind to an attribute value. Action, of course, is the method to actually execute to handle the event.

Answer (score 3):

**aura:valueInit** event is automatically fired when an app or component is initialized, but before rendering. The part **name="init"** tag handles this.